# Connect 2 monitors to one system and show different pictures on either

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, display, multiple-monitors, lcd

I want to connect 2 LCD monitors to 1 CPU to show different tasks on different monitors. For example, I want 1 monitor to display a video and the other one to display a stock trading platform.

How can I do this in Windows XP and Windows 7?

Comment: Make sure that you have correct drivers installed, make sure you are extending display not duplicating.

Answer (score 1):

You plug the monitors into the video card. Windows has supported this for ages.

You just need enough available video ports of the appropriate type, and it should just work. Windows will detect this, let you drag around monitors in display settings, and you can drag and drop windows between them. Its well supported and not rocket surgery.